# Using a Queue<T> in a PropertyGrid

Tags: c#, queue, propertygrid

I am using a Queue for a property, and it shows it as a collection in the propertygrid.  The only issue, is I can't edit anything inside of it, it shows them as just "Objects" and everything is read only.  I know Vector2 works fine in a propertygrid because I have a few of those by themselves.  I've been googling, and found something about making a ContainerEditor, but not sure how to make one for a Queue, since it isn't a custom class.

Am I reading this right, or searching for the wrong things?

Answer (score 1):

You need to write TypeConverter and UITypeEditor for converting and editing Queue object. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302326.aspx#usingpropgrid_topic6a) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302334.aspx) article for how to go about it. Both articles are bit dated but should be relevant - if there is something simpler has been come with later version of .NET then I am aware of it (you can try googling).

Now, for above to work, you need to decorate the class/type with attributes which is not possible if you use Queue. I will suggest that you inherit a dummy/wrapper class from Queue and apply attributes it. You can even choose specific T in your wrapper class if it make sense (e.g. class `MyQueue : Queue<string> { }`). Change your property type to use your wrapper class.